# Who picks the team's pitstop location in F1?

Tags: formula-1

I've seen a lot of F1 replay recently and noticed Mercedes pitstop is the first entry or should we say, "at the front gate of the pitstop entry". Here is my sketchy image.

[image]

So, I do know that in pitstop, there are speed limit, so no car will have advantages on this matter. But what if a situation like Fernando Alonso's happens where he punctured two of his tires (if I'm not mistaken).

In this case, of course, his speed in pit entry will be slower than regulated. But, if his team get the pitstop at front entry, he will have changed the tires much earlier than if his team get the pitstop at the end (closest to the exit entry).

So, how does the FIA or teams pick their pitstop entry place?

Because let says a situation happen to Russel (Mercedes) and Leclerc (Ferrari). Then Russell will have a slight advantage since Mercedes pitstop is at the entry of the pitstop.